# How do I add multiple CTests that compares output to known good output files?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a CMake project to which I'm trying to add tests using CTest.  I have a dozen or so input files with a `.txt` suffix which my program converts to a file of the same name with a `.out` tacked on to the end.  I have both the input files (`alpha.txt`, `beta.txt`, etc.) and output files (`alpha.txt.out`, `beta.txt.out`, etc.) in a `test` subdirectory.  What I am trying to do is add tests in a cross-platform way.  Unfortunately, my program `fargulate` creates the output file in the same directory as the input file, and to maintain backward compatibility, I'm unable to change that.  To avoid polluting the source tree, I copy the input file to the the current binary directory before running the test.  So the desired effect is this:

1. copy the input `.txt` file
2. run `fargulate` on the copied file
3. compare the actual output to the desired output

I have attempted to write a test to do this using the `cmake -E` syntax for portability, but it doesn't seem to work.  The tests always claim to have passed even when the files are different.

My efforts, shown here, are not only ugly, but they don't even work.  Is there a better, more elegant way to do this?

Here's what I have so far:

### test/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_test(NAME Runs COMMAND fargulate)

function(do_test arg)
  add_test(NAME ${arg} 
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -D TESTDIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/testone.cmake" ../src/fargulate "${arg}.txt"
  )
endfunction(do_test)

do_test(alpha)
do_test(beta)
do_test(gamma)
do_test(delta)
```

### test/testone.cmake

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy "${TESTDIR}/${CMAKE_ARGV6}" "${CMAKE_ARGV6}")
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_ARGV5}" -o "${CMAKE_ARGV6}")
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E compare_files "${TESTDIR}/${CMAKE_ARGV6}.out" "${CMAKE_ARGV6}.out")
```

### CMakeLists.txt  (top level)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(fargulate)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_subdirectory(src)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(test)
```

The `src` directory is just what it seems; the result is that the `fargulate` program is built within the `src` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The modification required is to look for a failure condition using a `FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`.  In this case, it's as simple as modifying the `do_test` function to include these three lines:

```
  set_tests_properties(${arg} PROPERTIES
    FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "are different"
  )
```